# Connectedness of topological subspaces

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I'm studying general topology and a question has come to my mind.

[Definition of *connected topological space* and *connected subset* of a topological space] We have defined a connected topological space to be a space that (viz. such that its underlying set) cannot be written as the union of two non-empty and disjoint open subsets. The notion extends to subsets by means of the subspace topology, viz. a subset of a topological space is said to be connected in it if, when endowed with the subspace topology, it's a connected topological space.

Does the following claim hold? *If a subset of a topological space is such that every clopen of the space either contains it or is disjoint from it, then the subset is connected in the space*.

[Some observations] The converse can be easily proved to be true. I am aware that connected spaces can be characterised as those whose only clopens are the empty set and the whole underlying set, but I don't know how to address the problem since I suppose that clopens of a subspace have no general relation with the clopens of the space. I noticed that, when the subset coincides with the whole space, the claim is true, being equivalent to the latter condition on clopens.

[Definition of *clopen subset* of a topological space] A subset of a topological space is said to be (a) clopen (i.e. closed-and-open) if it is both open and closed in the space.

Comment: What does clopen means ?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Here, "clopen" means "clopen set", where a clopsen set is one which is both closed and open.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the problem. But as you already said, if $X$ is connected, then the only clopen subsets are $X$ and $\varnothing$, so any $A \subset X$ satisfies the condition that clopen subsets of $X$ either contain $X$ or are disjoint from $A$. But certainly $A$ needs not be connected.

Comment: Your assertion is equivalent for your subspace to be connected, but you have plenty of non open subsets that are connected

Comment: I'm confused. Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $\Delta$ denote the set of clopen subsets of $X$. Let $C=\{\varnothing, X\}$. Then your "converse" is that if $X$ is connected, then $\Delta=C$. So the converse of the converse (which should be your original question again) is that if $\Delta=C$, then $X$ is connected. But that's not your italicized question. So I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @DavidGao I'm not sure to have explained well the problem too... Anyway, the point is that you don't a priori know that the topological space is connected: you're only trying to characterise those subspaces which are such basing on the clopen of the space (which may of course be non-trivial).

Comment: There was a "fatal" mistake in the italic statement, I've just fixed it.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace The question isn't equivalent to the subset being connected. As David said, if the space itself is connected, then every subset (including disconnected ones) satisfies the given property, because the only two clopen subsets are nothing and everything.

Comment: David's comment still provides negative answers to the corrected question. If $X$ is connected, then $X$ has too few clopen subsets to use to characterize any interesting property of a subset.

Comment: @AmandaWealth I mean, again, just choose a connected space with a non-connected subspace to begin with, and clearly the assertion is false because the only clopen subsets of the entire space are the empty set and the entire space, so either contains or is disjoint from the non-connected subspace. Does this answer your question then?

Comment: @user469053 That's a good point. As a result, any non-connected subspace of a connected space would disprove the claim, since for it the "if" clause would hold, without in fact being connected. Thank you.

Comment: It's now crystal clear, thank you. @DavidGao

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a counterexample that may further your investigation. Let X =$A \cup B$, such that A and B are open. Clearly A and B are both also clopen. Let S be a subset of X such that every clopen subset of X contains it. [Clearly S is disconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ9dB.jpg)